# What's the diff between "Committed Bytes" and "Pool Nonpaged Bytes"

Tags: perfmon

I have seen on some blogs the differences regarding Committed Bytes and Pool Nonpaged Bytes. I  thought both were reserved memories for NT systems that cannot be written to a `pagefile.sys`. So what is the diffenrence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2267427

> **Memory, Committed Bytes:** This is a measure of the demand for virtual
>   memory. It shows how many bytes have been allocated by processes and
>   to which the operating system has committed a RAM page frame or a page
>   slot in the pagefile (or both). As Committed Bytes grows above the
>   available RAM, paging increases, and the amount of the pagefile in use
>   also increases. At some point, paging activity starts to significantly
>   affect perceived performance.

From "[Pushing the Limits of Windows: Paged and Nonpaged Pool](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-paged-and-nonpaged-pool/ba-p/723789)" by Mark Russinovich

> **Nonpaged Pool**
>   The kernel and device drivers use nonpaged pool to store
>   data that might be accessed when the system can’t handle page faults.
>   The kernel enters such a state when it executes interrupt service
>   routines (ISRs) and deferred procedure calls (DPCs), which are
>   functions related to hardware interrupts. Page faults are also illegal
>   when the kernel or a device driver acquires a spin lock, which,
>   because they are the only type of lock that can be used within ISRs
>   and DPCs, must be used to protect data structures that are accessed
>   from within ISRs or DPCs and either other ISRs or DPCs or code
>   executing on kernel threads. Failure by a driver to honor these rules
>   results in the most common crash code, IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL.
>
> Nonpaged pool is therefore always kept present in physical memory and
>   nonpaged pool virtual memory is assigned physical memory. Common
>   system data structures stored in nonpaged pool include the kernel and
>   objects that represent processes and threads, synchronization objects
>   like mutexes, semaphores and events, references to files, which are
>   represented as file objects, and I/O request packets (IRPs), which
>   represent I/O operations.